# No qualifying bean of type [] is defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I just started learning Spring and tried to make a basic Spring program but I can't resolve this error. Below is the code:

**Student.java**

```
@Component
public class Student {
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

**Configuration Class**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("springfirst1")

public class ConfigClass {
public Student getStudent(){
    return new Student();
}
}
```

**Main Class**

```
public class SpringFirst1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("ConfigClass.class");
    Student s1 = context.getBean(Student.class);
    s1.setName("Adam");
    System.out.println(s1.getName());
}
```

}

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [springfirst1.Student] is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:985)
at springfirst1.SpringFirst1.main(SpringFirst1.java:13)
```

Comment: Update the Java classes with the package declaration. It would be helpful to debug the problem

Comment: The mistake is in AnnotationConfigApplicationContext argument. Check the documentation and correct it, This will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following changes in the `ApplicationContext`  argument would solve this problem.

**Main Class**

```
public class SpringFirst1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ConfigClass.class);
    Student s1 = context.getBean(Student.class);
    s1.setName("Gaurav");
    System.out.println(s1.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public Student getStudent(){
        return new Student();
    }
```

This is not necessary if you put @Component above you class:

If you want to use java configuration you have to put @Bean above it:

```
@Bean
public Student getStudent(){
  return new Student();
 }
```

EDIT: Check Arun answer :-)